# How can I return state before 'onclick' method?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `onclick` method which makes a text style 'bold', and I need to back it to normal if I click second time.
How can I do that ?

```
<button onclick="boldText()">B</button>

function boldText() {
    document.getElementById('txt-area').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
```

Comment: It would be much simpler and more reliable with a CSS class, like `.bold { font-weight: bold; }`. Then it’s just `document.getElementById("txt-area").classList.toggle("bold");`.

Answer (score 1):

`setBold` function check if element `fontWeight` is `bold` then set it to `bold` and vice versa

```js
function setBold() {
    var element= document.getElementById('txt-area');
    
    if (element.style.fontWeight == 'bold') {
        element.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
    } else {
        element.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setBold()">Toggle font Weight</button>
<p id='txt-area'>Test Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable, and if you click increment it by `1`. You could do the following:

```js
let numOfClicks = 0;

function boldText() {
  numOfClicks++;
  document.getElementById('txt-area').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  if (numOfClicks >= 2 ) {
    document.getElementById('txt-area').style.fontWeight = 'normal';
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="boldText()">B</button>
<p id='txt-area'>This is the text area</p>
```

Comment: Most likely because it doesn't toggle anymore after the 2nd click.

Comment: ok, fair enough probably, although the question didn't say he wanted to toggle this as far as I could see.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var clickNum = 0;
      function boldText() {
        if(clickNum == 0){
          document.getElementById('txt-area').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
          clickNum++;
        } else {
          document.getElementById('txt-area').style.fontWeight = '';
          clickNum--;
        }
      }
```

Comment: "Try this..." answer is bad one's. Explain what you did and why it works.